# ksh wildcard filename parameter to use in for loop

Tags: ksh

I am attempting to write a shell script that will take a file name with a wildcard, find all files matching that pattern in current directory, and copy them. My problem is every time I try and use a variable only the first match echo's and thats it.

```
./copyfiles.ksh cust*.txt

#! /usr/bin/ksh
IN_FILE=${1}
for file in $IN_FILE
do
    echo "$file"
done

cust1.txt
```

This seems to only match the first one even though cust1.txt, cust2.txt, and cust3.txt all exist and when I run it with for file in cust*.txt it works.

Answer (score 2):

The shell expands your argument of "`cust*.txt`" to a list then passes the list to your script, which then only processes `$1` which is `cust1.txt`.

You want to use `$@` which will process all arguments passed:

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh
for file in "$@"
do
    echo "$file"
done
```

I believe there is a limit to how many arguments can be passed this way though.  How many files are you having to process?  Make sure your version of the shell can handle the number of arguments you are likely to process. If I recall you may need a solution utilizing `xargs` but I'm a tad rusty to help with that.

Answer (score 2):

In `./copyfiles.ksh cust*.txt` the files cust*.txt will be expanded first.

When you do not want to change your `copyfiles.ksh` script. call it with

```
./copyfiles.ksh "cust*.txt"
```

You can also change your script, with something like

```
IN_FILE="$@" # INFILES would be a better name
```